# Change color for multiple plots in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use the R cookbook function `multiplot` to produce a picture with several plots that visualize the values (discrete) from a table by a color scheme. In order to do so I wanted to make a list of ggplot objects in a loop. I set the color by `color=as.factor(unlist(colors2[i,]))[sort.cd34]`, but this leads to the same color coding in all the plots, obviously because the same line of `colors2` is used every time instead of depending on `i` in the loop.

```
nr.plot <- 9
colors2 <- Table1[1:nr.plot,11:38]
snp.plot <- list()
for (i in 1:nr.plot){
  p1 <- ggplot(scan,aes(x=c(1:28),y=cd34,color=as.factor(unlist(colors2[i,]))[sort.cd34])) +geom_point() + scale_color_manual(breaks=c("0","1","2"),values=c("yellow","orange","red")) 
  snp.plot[[i]] <- p1
}
```

How can I avoid that and get different factor lists from colors2 for every plot object? I don't know whether it is relevant, but 
`p1$mapping` gives the output:

```
* x      -> c(1:28)
* y      -> cd34
* colour -> as.factor(unlist(colors2[i, ]))[sort.cd34]
```

Shouldn't the variable `colour` contain my vector of factors from colors2 for the whole thing to work?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are many ways, but one is to join your colour column to `scan`, so something akin to `ggplot(cbind(scan, col = as.factor(coors2[[i]])), aes(color = col, ...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the color *aesthetic* with the color *scale*. Setting `aes(color = some.factor)` simply tells ggplot that color should change with the levels of `some.factor`. This alone does not set the colors used, and ggplot will use the same defaults on each iteration of the loop. To alter the actual colors that are used for different levels, you need to set them in `scale_color_manual()`. Right now, you are setting:

```
scale_color_manual(breaks=c("0","1","2"),values=c("yellow","orange","red"))
```

on every iteration of the loop, so of course all colors are the same.

In your example, the following might work:

```
scale_color_manual(values = unlist(colors2[i, ]))
```